# sed command usage in multiple for loops

Tags: linux, bash

I am writing a shell script which is as below:

```
#!/bin/bash
try="7200005781
8110892533
9585055818
9942609990
9943985228"
filename="TAMILNADU,917373342777,POSTPAID
TAMILNADU,917639403547,POSTPAID
TAMILNADU,917639989185,POSTPAID
TAMILNADU,917667882223,POSTPAID
TAMILNADU,918012888899,POSTPAID
TAMILNADU,918098909992,POSTPAID
TAMILNADU,917200005781,POSTPAID
TAMILNADU,918110892533,POSTPAID
TAMILNADU,919585055818,POSTPAID
TAMILNADU,919942609990,POSTPAID
TAMILNADU,919944040565,POSTPAID
TAMILNADU,919943985228,POSTPAID"

#echo -e "\n${try[@]}" -> works
#echo -e "\n"           -> works
#echo -e "\n${filename[@]}" -> works

for j in "${try[@]}"
do
    for k in "${filename[@]}"
    do     
        sed -i 's/$j//g' $k > master.txt
    done
done
```

I am trying to match 'try' and 'filename'

If any number of matches from 'try' in 'filename'

I need to remove that entry from 'filename'

Kindly help me with this.

Comment: No closing quotes on `filename`, also single quotes on sed. Probably other problems as well.

Comment: Yes, i know there are some syntax errors in sed.

And yea, forgot to close filename.

Comment: @tripleee strictly speaking this is not a duplicate as op is asking for rows _not_ matching rather than a join.

Comment: @hack_on Thanks for the comment.  This is a common enough task that it's probably possible to find a different duplicate which more precisely answers this specific case, but my search fu didn't bring it up yesterday.  If you find a better duplicate, do please link it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way to do it within the script you have, but requires writing one file.

```
#!/bin/bash
try="7200005781
8110892533
9585055818
9942609990
9943985228"
filename="TAMILNADU,917373342777,POSTPAID
TAMILNADU,917639403547,POSTPAID
TAMILNADU,917639989185,POSTPAID
TAMILNADU,917667882223,POSTPAID
TAMILNADU,918012888899,POSTPAID
TAMILNADU,918098909992,POSTPAID
TAMILNADU,917200005781,POSTPAID
TAMILNADU,918110892533,POSTPAID
TAMILNADU,919585055818,POSTPAID
TAMILNADU,919942609990,POSTPAID
TAMILNADU,919944040565,POSTPAID
TAMILNADU,919943985228,POSTPAID"

echo "$filename" > /tmp/filename_zz.txt
echo "$try" | xargs -L 1 -I{} grep {} /tmp/filename_zz.txt 
rm /tmp/filename_zz.txt
```

EDIT: didn't realise we want to remove the items, not match them ... replace the last 3 lines of above script with these lines ... credit to @Florin

```
echo "$filename" > /tmp/filename_zz.txt
echo "$try" > /tmp/try_zz.txt
grep -F -vf /tmp/try_zz.txt /tmp/filename_zz.txt
rm /tmp/try_zz.txt
rm /tmp/filename_zz.txt
```

Comment: do i have to explicitly create filename_zz.txt ? or just running your code will work out?

Comment: You just run the script and it will create the file, then delete it when its done.

Comment: what if, I interchange the variables in echo? 
echo "$try" > /tmp/filename_zz.txt
echo "$filename" | xargs -L 1 -I{} grep {} /tmp/filename_zz.txt

Actually, your code fetches all the entries related to try.. i need to print other numbers. Pls help.

Comment: Updated answer as I had not understood the question correctly.

Comment: your edit serves my purpose.

Thanks a tonn for it. And not forgetting Florin too... thanks guys.. you ppl r amazing. :)

Answer (score 0):

That's simple if you have the records in files:

```
egrep -vf try filename
```

Comment: yes Florin.. this works like charm.. however, the situation is to use it via variable.